# If I do a full MySql restore from a dump file, will the user permissions and privileges restore aswell?

Tags: mysql, java

I had some weird stuff happen after rebooting my system. Something changed that I did not do. Now none of my java client applications can connect to my main mysql database - they get the error

> SQL EXCEPTION: ACCESS DENIED FOR USER ''@''...

I've changed permissions, changed root password, everything I can think of and nothing has worked to fix this problem...

So if I do a complete restore, would that bring all settings and data back to its original state?

Comment: `DENIED FOR USER ''@''` implies that the connection has no user nor password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if your mysqldump is backing up all databases!

If not, for future make sure you use `--all-databases` with mysqldump.

**Alert**
but this will take your system to the state what it was earlier...
If you know what your java programs are connecting using (user-name and host) then you can choose to fix the permissions for that!!

Comment: Okay, i know the user-name and host for each instance, I think I have some issues with the permissions on them and thats why nothing is working.